# Is it bad to load twitter bootstrap modals statically?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple question. Is it bad to load twitter bootstrap modals statically? I am creating a search page. When a user hits the search button and his or her query returns one or more results, I have a loop inside my view(HTML) that for each result, the result will have its specific modal, which is shown, for example, when a user hits "view more" link.

That means that for each result, whether the user needs the modal or not, will have a preloaded modal in the HTML source code. Now I know there is another way, which is the AJAX, but I'm not too familiar with it yet.

Is it a bad practice? I feel like it is. Just for the record, I'm using PHP.

EDIT: If you guys have suggestions/better ways, I'd be glad to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what's in your modals and how many results are returned. Bootstrap modals are nothing more than styled HTML, so there's nothing wrong with statically "baking" them into your HTML file server-side (other than it will use up more bandwidth to send it).

But...if you have a lot of results or the modals have a lot of info, I'd say look into a dynamic solution, especially if you don't expect users to click every "View More" link.

Just from a personal perspective, I'd always try to go dynamic for scalability.